# Footer with next/previous posts

Tags: footer, previous, next

I'm looking for something to create a multi footer with previous / next posts. The footer needs to know if the current post is the newest (1st, 2nd and 3rd newest), oldest (3rd, 2nd, and oldest) or in between.

As an example: [image]

The old / new links include title & thumbnail.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand the question, sorry in that case.

But can't you just retrieve the last 6 posts excluding the current? Something like:

```
global $post;

$footer_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( array('post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => '6', 'exclude' => $post->ID), 1 );

if ( ! empty($footer_posts) ) { foreach ( $footer_posts as $post ) {
  setup_postdata($post);
  echo '<div style="float:left; margin-left:20px;">';
  echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">';
  the_post_thumbnail('thumb');
  echo '<br /><h4 style="text-align:center;">' . get_the_title() . '</h4></a>';
  echo '</div>';
} }

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Hey G.M. thanks for your comments but what don't you understand of the question? Then I can edit it.. I tried your solution but it seems not to work.

Comment: there was an error in code. I've edited the code adding som html _decorations_. Note that this works on **single post view**. For me works perfectly, what exactly doesn't work for you?